# How can I add an object to a group when it is created?

Tags: python, django

I need to save an object to a group at the time of creation. 
I have Porumbei and Grupuri models. Each Porumbei must belong to a Grupuri. I have 4 different Grupuri and depending on form fields value, it must be added to the right Grupuri.
Is there a 'best practice'?
Below are may models.

## Grupuri

```
class Grupuri(models.Model):
    """ Definire model pentru salvarea porumbeilor in grupuri"""
    nume_grup = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    porumbei = models.ManyToManyField(Porumbei, related_name="grup_porumbei")
```

## Porumbei

```
class(models.Model):
    id_porumbel = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    serie_inel = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=False, blank=False, unique=True,
                              help_text="Seria de pe inel. Ex: RO 123456")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(StatusPorumbei, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    ...
```

## My view

```
def porumbelnou(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # crescator=request.user - folosit pentru a filtra porumbeii crescatorului logat

        form = AdaugaPorumbel(request.POST, request.FILES, crescator=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.crescator = request.user
            obj.save()
            return redirect('porumbei')
    else:
        # crescator=request.user - folosit pentru a filtra porumbeii crescatorului logat

        form = AdaugaPorumbel(crescator=request.user)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    template = loader.get_template("adaugare-porumbel.html")
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

## What I try but it got me MultiValueDictKeyError on 'id_porumbel'

```
if form.data['is_active']:
    toti = Grupuri.objects.get(nume_grup__exact="Toti porumbeii")
    toti.porumbei.add(form.data['id_porumbel'])
```

Comment: In your case you must first save the `Porumbel` model and then to update the `porumbei` field from `Grupuri`. I suggest you to move the many to many field in the `Porumbei` model to not update every time the `Grupuri` model. Dacă vrei vorbim pe chat

Comment: Let's talk on chat if you can help me